# Teradata Trigger or check constraint to check the date range from a different table

Tags: triggers, teradata, check-constraints, teradata-sql-assistant

I am looking for a solution to the implement the following logic in teradata. I would really appreciate suggestions.

Before inserting a row in table_1, I want to have a check for the date value, it should be between the date range- effective_dt and expiration_dt in the table_2.

**Table_1 (fact table):**

```
Account_num  Tran_dt     Tran_amt

12345        2019-05-12  120,000
```

**Table_2 (dim table):**

```
Account_num  effective_dt  expiration_dt

12345        2018-01-01     2019-04-28
```

In this case the table_1 insert statement should fail because the transaction date is out of the account's activation date range.

Thanks!

Comment: I have looked at different options - creating a trigger and using check constraint. However I am unable to find a solution that can use a check against a different table. Here is kind of an idea that I had- >CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER xyz
>BEFORE INSERT ON table_1
>FOR EACH ROW
>BEGIN
>IF :new.TRAN_DT > (select max(dw_expr_dt) FROM table_2 WHERE t.acct_id = >:new.acct_id)
>THEN abort 'Invalid transaction date for the Account';
END IF;
END;

Comment: One option is to write a stored procedure (SP) that handles the `INSERT` logic into `table 1` and only call the `SP` when adding new rows.

Comment: That's not valid Teradata syntax for a trigger. This would be valid, but might not meet your needs: `REPLACE TRIGGER database_name.trigger_name
 BEFORE INSERT ON database_name.fact_tbl
 REFERENCING NEW ROW n
 FOR EACH ROW
 (ABORT 'Invalid transaction date for Account'
   FROM database_name.dimension_tbl d
   WHERE n.Account_num = d.Account_num
   AND n.Tran_dt NOT between d.effective_dt and d.expiration_dt;);
`

Answer (score 0):

See if this does what you are asking:

```
REPLACE TRIGGER database_name.trigger_name
 AFTER INSERT ON database_name.fct
 REFERENCING NEW TABLE AS n
 FOR EACH STATEMENT
 (ABORT 'Invalid transaction date for Account'
 FROM  n
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM database_name.dim d
   WHERE n.Account_num = d.Account_num
   AND n.Tran_dt between d.effective_dt and d.expiration_dt);
   );
```

Though this is an "AFTER INSERT" trigger in terms of when it fires, it still will be enforced *before* the INSERT can be committed.